# Android viewing an arraylist in text view

Tags: android, textview

I have a program that has a text input and a button. When I type something into the input and press the button I want that `String` to be added to a `String Arraylist` and have that `Arraylist` displayed in a `TextView`. Right now I have a method:

```
public void addString(View view)
{
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_choice);
    String message = editText.getText().toString();
    choices.add(message);
}
```

*"edit-choices"* is the name of the text input and *"choices"* is the name of the array list. First of all am I doing this correctly? Second, how to I get the text view to display the contents of "choices". Right now my `TextView` id is just `textView1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please keep in mind that it is not the best way to show list items in a `TextView`. You can do this using a `ListView`. Anyhow, see pseudo code below (didn't test that in Eclipse, however, it should show how it is basically going to work):

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity {

  Vector<String> choices = new Vector<String>();

  public void onCreate(Bundle ....) {
    (Button) myButton =  (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    myButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean button.onClick() {
          addString();
          TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view);

          String listRepresentation = "";
          for (String choice : choices)
            if ("".equals(listRepresentation))
              listRepresentation  =       choice; else 
              listRepresentation  = ", " +choice;

          textView.setText(listRepresentation );
        }
     });
  }

  public void addString(View view)
  {
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_choice);
    String message = editText.getText().toString();
    choices.add(message);
  }
}
```

So simply assign an `OnClickListener` to your button that does what you need.

Comment: Ok if I were to use a list view, how would I add the strings to that? I don't see a set(string) method for list views

Comment: First of all you'd need a ListView declaration in your layout; in the code retrieve the ListView reference and assign values to it: `ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mylist); String[] choicesArray = (String[]) choices.toArray(); ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values); listView.setAdapter(adapter);` see http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html for more details; *pls note fixed cast*

Answer (score 0):

The question is how you want the Text to be displayed...
Either like a list view or just as a normal text.
If you want to show the text as a normal text in the text view you can simply do something like this.

```
for(String msg : choices)
{
textView1.setText(textView1.getText()+msg);
}
```

If you want the choices to be displayed in list view you need to set an adapter to the list view using the choices that you have.

Comment: there is no `foreach` in Java. Also, using `+` for Stirng-concatenation will internally create a `StringBuilder`-instance, every time you do it. Take a look at my answer.

Comment: Sorry to say, but this is simply wrong: `foreach` does definitely exist! Regarding the StringBuilder you are right, though I wouldn't see this as a serious issue - as long as the lists do not exceed 10000 entries ;)

Comment: @André maybe I wasn't clear: A for-each in Java is called an "extended for loop". There is **no** `foreach`-keyword in java. G_S corrected his answer to the right syntax.

Comment: Never saw that `foreach` keyword - would have been better, if G_S had labeled his change. Sorry!

Comment: yes i got addicted to .net environment and applied the same syntax here too.. anywayz thanks for correcting me :) and moreover i mentioned the edit...

Answer (score -1):

> First of all am I doing this correctly?

If it works for you, sure. I would maybe cache the `EditText` so you don't have to "find" it every time you want to access it's content.

---

Your only "problem" here is, that a `TextView` has no method that accepts a `List<String>`. So, you'll need to make a *single* string out of your list of strings.

You can simply iterate over the list and con-cat them together:

```
StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
for (String s : choices){
  b.append(s+"\n");
}
textview.setText(b.toString());
```

This will simply build one string from all the items in your list, adding line-breaks after every item.

You'll need to set your `TextView`'s [`android:inputType`-attribute](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3ainputType) to `textMultiLine`, so it will actually show you multiple lines.